# TFDQuery (contra BD Postgres) devuelve WIDEMEMO al recuperar select que incluye función en clausula select

Tags: postgresql, function, delphi

En Postgres tengo una función que devuelve text (He probado con varchar, con table.field%type obteniendo el mismo resultado)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.prueba6(ParamEnt numeric)
 RETURNS text -- t_formato.den_formato%type / varchar
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
...
end
$function$
;
```

al implementar una consulta en un control FIREDAC TFDQuery que incluye esta función

```
select val, prueba6(cod) from tabla;
```

, el valor obtenido en el TFDQuery es invariablemente WIDEMEMO, incluso si creo una vista en Postgre y me limito a hacer una consulta select * from vista (en el TFDQuery), o si hago select from (select...) sigo obteniendo WIDEMEMO.

Gracias de antemano por las molestias.  Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Resuelto.  Solo había que hacer cast del campo en el propio sql del TFDQuery:
(Eso si, haciendo select from (select...) no se puede hacer el cast directamente sobre el campo que invoca a la funcion.  Me explico.

En el sql del TFDQuery introducimos:

```
select val, pru::varchar(20)
from 
(select val, prueba6(cod) pru from tabla) Probando
```

Y ahora si vemos (Gracias al ::varchar(20) el resultado de aplicar la funcion en el resultado de la consulta.